# Running find_all() commands in a new view via Sublime Text Plugin changes it into an Instant File Search

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I am building an internal plugin for Sublime Text 3 to automate some changes we need done in our HTML.

I'm close to finishing it so we can start using it but I just have one small issue I can't seem to find a solution for.

The plugin will search for some specific HTML code, save them in a file and then modify the code in the view to reference some text in a json file. Then the plugin will open a new view and paste the contents of the file we saved some code in step 1. After which, I need to do some formatting in the new view (replace commas, quotes and brackets with a new line) and then run another internal sublime command in the new view.

The issue is after replacing the commas, quotes and brackets with a new line, the new view changes to an "Instant File Search" which messes with how the view runs the next command and inserts some garbage characters.

Example of the code:

```
    #Open new tab and paste the copied subheads
    newView = self.view.window().new_file(syntax="HTML.sublime-syntax")
    newView.insert(edit, 0, json.dumps(sections))

    # Clear any current selections in the new view
    newView.sel().clear()

    # Remove quotes, commas and square brackets and separate into new lines
    q = newView.find_all(r"(\x{0022}\,\s\x{0022})|(\[\x{0022})|(\x{0022}\])")
    for region in reversed(q):
        newView.sel().add(region)
        newView.replace(edit, region, "\n")

    # Clear any current selections in the new view
    newView.sel().clear()

    q = newView.find_all("{% r")
    for region in reversed(q):
        newView.sel().add(region)
        newView.replace(edit, region, "<p>{% r")

    # Clear any current selections in the new view
    newView.sel().clear()
    
    q = newView.find_all("endreplace %}")
    for region in reversed(q):
        newView.sel().add(region)
        newView.replace(edit, region, "endreplace %}</p>")
```

This is what it outputs in the new view:

[image: Example output]

If I click undo, I get the expected output which seems to mean sublime does something extra after running the last find_all code.

I haven't found anything online regarding this issue so I'm unable to try things to fix this.

Does anyone have an idea on how I should proceed?

P.S. One possible solution is to manually open a new view and run some commands but I'm trying to do all of that in 1 step using my plugin.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "instant file search" in Sublime; all find operations are done in a panel and no search prompt is ever displayed in the content of the file ***unless*** you have a third party plugin/package installed. I would try this in [Safe Mode](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/safe_mode.html) and see what happens. Something you're doing is either triggering an event listener a package created, or your code is invoking a non-core command of some sort.

Comment: @OdatNurd Running in Safe mode seems to work without issues. I'm not sure how to find what's causing the issue since the console doesn't provide anything out of the ordinary. Are you suggesting I add all my installed plugins one at a time in Safe Mode to see which is triggering the issue?

Comment: Generally you go the other way; open `PackageControl.sublime-Settings` in your User package, and copy the list of `installed_packages` into your `ignored_packages` setting in `Preferences.sublime-settings`; verify that the issue is gone. If so, comment out half of the packages in `ignored_settings` and test again, etc, so you can whittle down.

Comment: If ignoring all of the packages still shows the problem, the problem is a plugin in your `User` folder. In any case, the most likely culprits are packages that seem like they might be trying to do something search related, like some package to make Sublime behave more like Emacs or Vim or something.

Comment: @OdatNurd thanks a bunch. I'll start on this soon and will see how I go. Appreciate it.

Comment: @OdatNurd testing some more, I found that new_file() just creates a plain text file instead of following HTML syntax. Would you happen to know how I can create a new file that recognises HTML? I was not able to find resources online to help with this. 

I also tried opening an empty HTML file with open_file() but newView was not able to run any commands on it.

Comment: I tried newView.set_syntax_file("html") and newView.assign_syntax("html") and neither of them appear to work as well. @OdatNurd

Comment: `view.assign_syntax()` is the correct way, but you need to pass it the full syntax resource name. You can also create the new view and assign the syntax in one shot: `window.new_file(syntax="Packages/HTML/HTML.sublime-syntax")`

Comment: @OdatNurd the above worked for the syntax. Thank you.

Comment: @OdatNurd I've found the problem package interfering with my plugin. It's called [SidebarEnhancements](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SideBarEnhancements). Do you reckon I need to find an alternate similar plugin to that? I think the new_file() command is probably overlapping with that one.

Comment: Offhand no; I avoid all packages created by Tito because in the past he snuck tracking information in there for his own monetary gain. I use [FileManager](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FileManager) to do file related things which may or may not overlap what you use SBE for.

Comment: @OdatNurd thanks for that. FileManager doesn't seem to be interfering with my plugin. Helped me make some good progress. However I have a new issue unrelated to other plugins. After creating the new file, for some reason alternating blocks of code meant to manipulate the contents of the new file would be skipped. I tested it by having 4 blocks of code that would replace some characters and only 2 of them would run. find_all() would come up empty for 2 of the blocks when I know they shouldn't be. Would you know if there is some sort of timing issue?

Comment: offhand no, not without seeing a complete code example that exhibits the issue. There would be if you're trying to load a file as a part of the operation though; loads are async

Comment: @OdatNurd I've updated the code example in the post with the snippet that's causing the issue. I did some more testing and I was able to have my plugin doing everything if it's only running in the same file/view. However, operations in the new file/view behave weirdly.

Comment: You can't use the `edit` that you get in a `TextCommand`'s `run()` method to make edits to any `view` except the one for which the command is executing for. So in all likelyhood what you're seeing here is the result of undefined behaviour.

Comment: So I'm assuming that means I need to save the output from the first view externally and then manually create a new view and run a separate second command to paste the output and perform manipulations?

Comment: Generally speaking, you can `new_file()` to get a view, then `new_file.run_command('append', {'characters': 'string content here'})` to put the file content into it, then move the rest of your code to another `TextCommand` and invoke it the same way as the `insert` on that view, where you can use the `edit` as you like.

Comment: @OdatNurd thanks heaps mate. It's all good now. Your above suggestion has resolved my issue and I was able to add more features to my plugin. You can post it as an answer if you would like.